# Why does this PHP assignment in a loop always print the first value?

Tags: php

I'm very confused as to the output of this small piece of test code:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
while ($fn_retval = do_the_thing($count) !== false) {
    print $fn_retval."\n";
    $count++;
}

function do_the_thing($count) {
    if ($count > 3) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $count;
    }
}
?>
```

The output is:

```
$ php ./test.php 
1
1
1
1
```

So it is correctly performing 4 iterations but always printing the return value of the first iteration. I feel like I must have missed something really obvious because this makes no sense.

Can somebody explain what's going on here because it seems like I can't use that assign-and-check construct in the way I thought I could.

Comment: Just change it to `while ($fn_retval = do_the_thing($count))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the order in which

```
$fn_retval = do_the_thing($count) !== false
```

is evaluated.  If you check the [Operator Precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), you will see that `!==` is a higher precedence than `=`, so it's evaluated as

```
do_the_thing($count) !== false
```

and the result is then assigned to `$fn_retval`.

To force the order you are after, use brackets to explicitly do the assignment first...

```
while (($fn_retval = do_the_thing($count)) !== false) {
```

Comment: Precedence! Of course! I knew I was missing something obvious. With your modification it works like I expected it to.